# Is it worth Indexing day_of_week column?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, indexing

I have a users table that has a day_of_week column, it is an integer(0...6). Every day I have to run a script and iterate over the users of that day.

So, should I mark this column with an index for faster perfomance? The query will always return 1/7 of the total, I'm afraid it may occur the opposite effect if I add an index. Imagine a 10k-100k rows in the users table.

By the way I'm using PostgreSQL if it matters.

Comment: There are "lies, damned lies, and benchmarks"... but then there are "people and their opinions". Trust the benchmarks more :). ie try it, benchmark it, revert index or keep it.

Comment: I'd recommend getting that sort of logic out of your database layer. Applications should handle that sort of thing.

Comment: @Droogans No. Indeed the database is the right place to solve that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Don't index on that as its [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) is very low so a direct table scan is cheaper. It could only be worth if the result set should be sorted on it. But that would depend on other factors.

When a value is present in more than a few percents of the total rows of the table then a query filtering on it will have to visit most of the table's [pages](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/storage-page-layout.html) after finding them in the index. So there is no point in searching the index first as that is just double work.

Comment: It would be great if you describe a little on " table scan is cheaper". Thanks :)

Comment: Although I agree that it is probably not worth, we should also mention that PostgreSQL 9.2 finally introduced index only scans (depending on vaccum), which could be used to improve performance in that case (depends on the columns queries). Just mentioned for completeness sake.

Comment: @Markus Not in this case. An _index only scan_ as the name says would only scan the index where the only data that would exist would be the day of week. As the wanted data is on the table then it would not be an _index only scan_ as the table would have to be scanned.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto Sure you would need to add the needed (selected) columns to this index! If these is just on small numeric column, it might be worth.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, indexing doesn't make too much sense if the query is going to be pulling more than around 5% of the table.  But depending on the properties of the table, there  are other things to look into.  For example, in Postgres, take a look at [partitioning](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

> Partitioning refers to splitting what is logically one large table
>   into smaller physical pieces. Partitioning can provide several
>   benefits:
>
> Query performance can be improved dramatically in certain situations,
>   particularly when most of the heavily accessed rows of the table are
>   in a single partition or a small number of partitions. The
>   partitioning substitutes for leading columns of indexes, reducing
>   index size and making it more likely that the heavily-used parts of
>   the indexes fit in memory.
>
> When queries or updates access a large percentage of a single
>   partition, performance can be improved by taking advantage of
>   sequential scan of that partition instead of using an index and random
>   access reads scattered across the whole table.
>
> Bulk loads and deletes can be accomplished by adding or removing
>   partitions, if that requirement is planned into the partitioning
>   design. ALTER TABLE NO INHERIT and DROP TABLE are both far faster than
>   a bulk operation. These commands also entirely avoid the VACUUM
>   overhead caused by a bulk DELETE.
>
> Seldom-used data can be migrated to cheaper and slower storage media.

Or say the data is never updated, only insert appends. Something like a bitmap index could make sense.